# How to check if SuperTab and jedi-vim is activated?

Tags: vim, supertab, jedi-vim

As the title states, how do I check if a plugin is loaded?

When I hit *tab* (for SuperTab) all I get is the ordinary character "tab" inserted in my file and when I hit *ctrl-space* I just get thrown out of insert-mode (same behavior as hitting *ESC*)

Comment: Too bad rep to add "jedi-vim" as a tag =/

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with either plugin anyway.

Comment: Follow up to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193768/vim-supertab-and-jedi-vim

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `:scriptnames` command lists all scripts that have been sourced; check for the plugin name in its output. If it's missing, it is either due to a wrong installation or because `'runtimepath'` is incorrect.

Alternatively, if you know the mapping a plugin should define

```
:verbose imap <Tab>
```

will show the mapping and from which script is was set.

Programmatically, it is best to check for the canonical include guard `if exists('g:loaded_pluginname')` or for a defined command via `if exists(':PluginCommand')`.